# Arranging the $26$ English letters in a row given two constraints

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, combinations, inclusion-exclusion, combinatorics-on-words

> In how many ways can we arrange the $26$ English letters in a row so
>   that no two vowels are adjacent to each other, and each block of
>   consonant(s) (between $2$ vowels) is/are in alphabetical order?

---

Example of a valid arrangement:

$\underset{*}{\underbrace{RX}}E\underset{*}{\underbrace{BGMQ}}O\underset{*}{\underbrace{CDJY}}I\underset{*}{\underbrace{FKNZ}}U\underset{*}{\underbrace{HTV}}A\underset{*}{\underbrace{LPSW}}$

The $*$ means that the consonants are in alphabetical order, so it is valid.

---

Example of invalid arrangement:

$I\underset{\text{invalid}}{\underbrace{BRMQGW}}O\underset{*}{\underbrace{CDJY}}A\underset{*}{\underbrace{FKNZ}}U\underset{*}{\underbrace{HTV}}E\underset{*}{\underbrace{LPSX}}$

$R$ can not be before $M$, and $M$ can not be before $G$.

---

The result of my trial:

$\frac{1}{2}(\frac{26!}{21!})=26 \times 25 \times 24 \times 23 \times 22 \times \frac{1}{2}=3,946,800$ different arrangments. I am not sure about it. Please tell me if I am wrong.

Unfortunately, I have no knowledge about inclusion-exclusion principle.

---

Any help would be appreciated. THANKS!

Comment: This is actually a rather involved problem... one that I don't spot an immediately obvious solution to.  I'm sure that the answer isn't the one you gave as there are almost just as many ways to arrange 21 identical stars and the five vowels with no two vowels adjacent than your attempted answer.  We can show that there must be strictly more than your attempted answer by then modifying the result further based on whether the smallest letter in the second group of consonants is bigger or smaller than the smallest letter in the third group of consonants.

Comment: @JMoravitz Yeah ,, Thanks,, I understood why my answer was incorrect. But still could not solve. :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume that we consider the list of vowels to be only $A,E,I,O,U$ and we do not consider $Y$ to be a vowel.

We use here [Stirling Numbers of the Second Kind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_numbers_of_the_second_kind).  We use $\left\{\begin{matrix}n\\k\end{matrix}\right\}$ to denote the number of partitions of an $n$ element set into $k$ non-empty unlabeled subsets.

We recognize that a vowel may appear at the very front of the arrangement and/or at the very end, and so we may have either $4,5$ or $6$ blocks of consonants.  In each block of consonants, we will require that they appear in alphabetical order.

Once having partitioned our consonants into $k$ non-empty subsets, we may then decide in what order they appear and which (if any) of the blocks to the far left of the furthest left vowel or to the far right of the furthest right vowel are unused.

We then decide which vowel appears in which position separating the blocks.

We have then a final total of:

$$\left(\left\{\begin{matrix}21\\4\end{matrix}\right\}4! + 2\cdot \left\{\begin{matrix}21\\5\end{matrix}\right\}5! + \left\{\begin{matrix}21\\6\end{matrix}\right\}6!\right)5!$$

[Evaluated](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%28%28Stirling+number+of+the+second+kind+%2821%2C4%29%29*4%21+%2B+2*%28Stirling+number+of+the+second+kind+%2821%2C5%29%29*5%21+%2B+%28Stirling+number+of+the+second+kind+%2821%2C6%29%29*6%21%29*5%21) this becomes approximately $2.4\times 10^{18}$

Comment: Almost clear, the second term in the parentheses is containing $2$ as a factor, can you please explain why? Thanks

Comment: @Hussain-Alqatari because we needed to consider the arrangements like a...e...i...o...u... separate from arrangements like ...a...e...i...o...u where we left either the far left location for a block empty or we left the far right location for a block empty.

Comment: Your work is really appreciated. Thanks brother. +